# Why is this Cuscuta compacta purple?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I was recently browsing the web and came across this site abut the compact dodder.

[image]

https://gobotany.nativeplanttrust.org/species/cuscuta/compacta/

The image used to identify the plant shows it as purple. This struck me as odd, as those are usually a greenish-yellow. Why is this plant purple? Is it a special sub species? Is it perhaps another type of dodder entirely, and gobotany simply messed up? I think this image might actually show the Cuscuta glomerata, but I'm not sure. Please explain this discoloration. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this another gold-white/blue-black dress moment? I dont see any part of the plant in the foto as purple. The ground in the background is blue. My brain interprets this as photo being taken in havily purple tinged lighting, posibly grow lights. My brain performs sort of light balance and the plant appears to me yellow/brown (fruit) and green (leafs). Only part that seems slightly purple is the leaf underside. What part of the plant do you see as purple?

Answer (score 1):

the Genus [*Cuscuta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuscuta) has over 200 species varying in color from yellow, to orange, and purple (sometimes but rarely can also be green).

The organism in the photo is not likely to be a subspecies of the usual dodders you find in your area, instead it is likely to be a different species entirely (while still belonging to the same genus).

The rope dodder (*Cuscuta compacta*) is very possibly the species you are looking at. However, I am also convinced that [*Cuscuta europea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuscuta_europaea) is a possible candidate, particularly due to this photo of the species that I got from the European Nature Information System ([EUNIS](https://eunis.eea.europa.eu/species/168822)) web site:

[image]

I must admit that I do not know nor have access to photos of all the different species of the Cuscuta genus to make a truly objective analysis of your image however I hope this information as a minimum leads to some new insight on the matter.